# I have two Json Objects. By using Scala how can i merge these two?

Tags: json, scala, gson

```
val jsonReq = {"name":"Scott", "age":"33"}
val jsonRes = {"name":"Scott", "location":"London"}
```

and `combinedJson` should be

```
val combinedJson = {"name":"Scott", "age":"33", "location":"London"}
```

I have no idea about this in Scala, since I am new to that.

can someone help in this?

Comment: Hey Sathya, you got some great answers already. Just for the next time: A google search for json libraries in scala gives you very good results for tutorials. Read some documentation there. Try something yourself. 

scastie is a great resource for trying stuff out without having to install anything.
Tell us what you already tried and why it is not working. Then people are more inclined to also upvote your question. Hope you have more great questions coming in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) library to work with Json.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._


val a = parse(""" {"name":"Scott", "age":33} """)
val b = parse(""" {"name":"Scott", "location":"London"} """)

val c = a merge b
println(c.toString)

println(c \ "name")
println(c \ "age")
println(c \ "location")


implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val name: String = (c \ "name").extract[String]
println(s"name: $name")

val age: Int = (c \ "age").extract[Int]
println(s"age: $age")

case class Person(name: String, age: Int, location: String)
val p = c.extract[Person]
println(p)
```

output will be:

```
JObject(List((name,JString(Scott)), (age,JInt(33)), (location,JString(London))))
JString(Scott)
JInt(33)
JString(London)
name: Scott
age: 33
Person(Scott,33,London)
```

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Dijon](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon) library for safe parsing and merging of JSON objects.

1. Add the dependency in your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependency += "com.github.pathikrit" %% "dijon" % "0.3.0"
```

2. Add required imports:

```
import scala.language.dynamics._
import com.github.pathikrit.dijon._
```

3. Parse input JSON values and print a merged JSON value:

```
val jsonReq = parse("""{"name":"Scott", "age":"33"}""")
val jsonRes = parse("""{"name":"Scott", "location":"London"}""")
val jsonMerged = jsonReq ++ jsonRes
println(jsonMerged)
```

It will output:

```
{"name":"Scott", "age":"33", "location":"London"}
```